# Android alarm not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've been struggling with this for hours. I've also checked the documentation and several topics. I found this code in two topics, both guys said the code was working perfectly, but not on my computer. The first Toast appears, but the second one never. What is wrong?

```
public class HelloAndroid2 extends Activity {  


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

 public final class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
 }
```

}

Comment: Please show your AndroidManifest.xml. You should declare your broadcast receiver in the manifest and the action it would react to

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Actually you dont need to specify the action since you use the class `AlarmReceiver.class` in the intent.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, make sure you have a receiver definition within the `<application>` tags, something like:

`<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">`

Edit:
Ok there are 2 ways to use your broadcast receiver.

1) From the code you have provided, `AlarmReceiver.java` that will contains:

```
public final class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
 }
```

and `HelloAndroid2.java`:

```
public class HelloAndroid2 extends Activity {  


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

Like this, you can set your broadcast receiver to work with the `AndroidManifest.xml` and the tag `<receiver ...>`

2)2nd way. With this way, you can use just 1 file `HelloWorld2.java`:

In your activity, create your broadcast receiver and register it.

```
public class HelloWorld2 extends Activity {
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private String mName;


    BroadcastReceiver alarmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
        }
    };


    public static final String ACTION_NAME = "com.helloworld.MYACTION";
    private IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_NAME);


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(alarmReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, myFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, myFilter);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_NAME);        

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 1000), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, but still nothing. This is the .xml file:

   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

     <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>

        <activity android:name=".HelloAndroid2"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
[/code]

Comment: You should add this to your post and post something like "Edit", so that people knows that it s an additional information

Comment: Do you see at least the first toast message "Alarm set"?

Comment: Ok, the code you have posted. Is it in 2 files : HelloAndroid2.java and AlarmReceiver.java ?

Comment: 1 file. Only the package and the import rows are missing from the code, so as a matter of fact, this is the whole code.
I have also tried android:enabled="true"

Comment: Both solutions work perfectly. It's really weird, that if i put my code into two files it works, but in file it doesn't.
I've uploaded my file here, could you check if something is missing from it?
http://www.2shared.com/file/cqXGQgxQ/HelloAndroid2.html

Comment: It's because, if you embedded a broadcast receiver in an activity, you need to register it to the activity. More information at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter).

Comment: Thanks for the post, adding the receiver to the manifest fixed my code.

Comment: AH....... I can't tell you how much time I spent trying to figure this out. The manifest! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem until I found that I had put my Broadcast Receiver on a different package, not the general.

Simply changed:

```
<receiver android:name=".AndroidAlarmService" android:enabled="true" >
```

for:

```
<receiver android:name="com.MyCompany.MyPackage.AndroidAlarmService" android:enabled="true" >
```

Comment: thank you. It should be a warning from Android. I wasted an hour.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer above doesn't work for you then there is another way to ***not***  receive any callbacks when `AlarmManager` fires an expired alarm. You simply need to check this one out: *by sending the wrong `Intent` on instantiation of `PendingIntent`*. For example you wanted to receive a call `onReceive` on one of your receivers but you instantiated a `PendingIntent` via `getActivity` or `getService`, but what you actually meant is `getReceiver`.

When creating instance of `PendingIntent`, there are many ways to create it (`getService`, `getActivity`,`getReceiver`, `getForegroundService`:

if you want `Activity` the receiver of the intent then you:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_*);
```

if you want `BroadcastReceiver` the receiver of the intent:

```
PendingIntent.getReceiver(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_*);
```

if you want a foreground `Service` the receiver of the intent:

```
PendingIntent.getForegroundService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_*);
```

if you want a `Service` the receiver of the intent:

```
PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_*);
```

Also, make sure you intents are pointing to the correct class. (e.g. creating intents for Activity, Service etc.). You will **not** receive any call if you pass wrongfully like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class); // You wanted receiver

// PendingIntent was created in such a way 
// you wanted this to be received by an activity. 
// you will not receive any call if you set it up like this.
PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_*);
```

I also posted similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872880/onreceiver-of-broadcastreceiver-not-called-alarmmanager/45093355#45093355).

HTH