# onReceiver of BroadcastReceiver not called, AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am building a cab booking app, I need current location of the cab every 20 seconds.

I have defined a AlarmManager and need it to repeat itself every 20 seconds. But its not repeating itself regularly. Instead it repeated itself after 233 seconds, and just once. What am I doing wrong here ?

My HomeScreen has a inner class OnAlarmReceiver, in the onCreate of my HomeScreen I am calling AlarmManager

```
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), God.UPDATE_PENDING_INTERVAL, pi);
```

Inner class in HomeScreen

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // PullPendingRequests.acquireStaticLock(context);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Don't panik but your time is up!!!!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Log.d("Taxeeta:PullPendingRequets", "CallService Location");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, PullPendingRequests.class));
    }
}
```

My AndroidManifest file has

```
    <service
        android:name="com.taxeeta.support.PullPendingRequests"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />

    <receiver android:name=".com.taxeeta.HomeScreen.OnAlarmReceiver" />
</application>
```

Output of `adb shell dumpsys alarm`

```
 com.taxeeta
    51471ms running, 5248 wakeups
    5248 alarms: flg=0x4 cmp=com.taxeeta/.HomeScreen$OnAlarmReceiver
```

Output of `adb shell dumpsys alarm | grep taxeeta`

```
 ELAPSED_WAKEUP #7: Alarm{409303b0 type 2 com.taxeeta}
    operation=PendingIntent{408ba2d8: PendingIntentRecord{40887be8 com.taxeeta broadcastIntent}}
 com.taxeeta
    5248 alarms: flg=0x4 cmp=com.taxeeta/.HomeScreen$OnAlarmReceiver
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To fix it, I removed the inner class OnAlarmReceiver and fixed the androidmanifest.xml file.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.taxeeta.support.OnAlarmReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 8):

If the answer above doesn't work for you then there is another way to ***not***  receive any callbacks when `AlarmManager` fires an expired alarm. You simply need to check this one out: *by sending the wrong `Intent` on instantiation of `PendingIntent`*. For example you wanted to receive a call `onReceive` on one of your receivers but you instantiated a `PendingIntent` via `getActivity` or `getService`, but what you actually meant is `getReceiver`.

When creating instance of `PendingIntent`, there are many ways to create it (`getService`, `getActivity`,`getReceiver`, `getForegroundService`:

if you want `Activity` the receiver of the intent then you:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_*);
```

if you want `BroadcastReceiver` the receiver of the intent:

```
PendingIntent.getReceiver(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_*);
```

if you want a foreground `Service` the receiver of the intent:

```
PendingIntent.getForegroundService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_*);
```

if you want a `Service` the receiver of the intent:

```
PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_*);
```

Also, make sure you intents are pointing to the correct class. (e.g. creating intents for Activity, Service etc.). You will **not** receive any call if you pass wrongfully like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class); // You wanted receiver

// PendingIntent was created in such a way 
// you wanted this to be received by an activity. 
// you will not receive any call if you set it up like this.
PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_*);
```

I also posted similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872880/onreceiver-of-broadcastreceiver-not-called-alarmmanager/45093355#45093355).

HTH

Comment: This ^.. When using a Receiver with AlarmManager you need to use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...)` and it's worrking like magic ;)

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code worked for me and make sure you have added reciever in android manifest file.

```
AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
                         PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// Start 20 seconds after boot completed
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
//
// Fetch every 20 seconds
// InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                       cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*20, pending);
```

Comment: Nope, does not work. OnAlarmReceiver, onReceive is also not being called.

Comment: Same here nothing on alarmmanager works for me.  I've tried all the suggestions for this.  Not sure what to do pretty stuck

Comment: That was so long ago not even sure what I needed this for.  Sorry man if I remember I'll post it up.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions didn't work for me.

Additionally, registering dynamically via code did the trick:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.NOTIFY");

//Register the receiver
context.registerReceiver(new OnAlarmReceiver(),new IntentFilter());
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still stuck - make sure your broadcast receiver is not crashing in the background. Make sure to check your LogCat!