# Update location every 30 seconds using Network Location Provider?

Tags: android

Every how many seconds is onLocationChanged called?
I would like to update the user's location every 30 seconds and I don't know how to do that.

P.S: I'm using Network Location Provider and not GPS. I know GPS is more accurate however I care about battery consumption and indoor locations.

This is my method it calls itself every a certain interval of time ( I don't know every how much exactly)..

```
TextView tvLong,tvLati;
    Button btnGet;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvLong =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLong);
    tvLati = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLati);
    btnGet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGet);
    btnGet.setOnClickListener(this);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            tvLati.setText("Location not available");
            tvLong.setText("Location not available");
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this); // I dont know what this exactly DOES.

}
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    lat =  (location.getLatitude());
    lng = (location.getLongitude());
    String valueLati = "Latitude: " + lat;
    String valueLong = "Longitude: " + lng;

    tvLati.setText(valueLati);
    tvLong.setText(valueLong);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you need to call `onLocationChanged` dont use `requestLocationUpdates`, since the API is completely unreliable on custom android phones (Samsung). Its better you use a AlarmManager and call `getLastKnownLocation`, and call `onLocationChanged` yourself.

Also note that getLastKnowLocation is buggy on Samsung phones, so you need to **trigger** the api to update behind scene's before you can expect it to return a good location.

Call this just before getLastKnownLocation, its a hack.

Note : that this does nothing to your app, just triggers the backend cache to have a good **Last Known Location**.

```
HomeScreen.getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        }
    });
```

**Option 2**

Junk all, and use the new `LocationClient` API's. That too has a getLastLocation kinda API, you can use with AlarmManager. With LocationClient you wont need to bother about bestprovider, available provider, accuracy choice and sensors. LocationClient merges them all into 1 nice API.

**For Alarm Manager**

I got it working after some pain. So here goes, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872880/onreceiver-of-broadcastreceiver-not-called-alarmmanager).

Comment: HI Siddharth, here HomeScreen means what?. i tried by using the location manager object, its returning me still NULL

Comment: HomeScreen is your home activity, or any activity under which you are calling this. Or even better, your applicationContext.