# BroadcastReceiver not working with alarm manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

guys i think the question is self explanatory.
I tried googling,and came across various solutions but none worked..

Here is what is working for me.
If i don't set a broadcast receiver the alarm manager works but if i set the broadcast receiver it doesn't work.
I have worked with broadcast receivers before .

I know there are two ways of setting up a broadcast as mentioned here

[Android alarm not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660823/android-alarm-not-working)

and i have tried both...

If any one wants the code i can post it here

```
public class Reminder extends Activity{
    DatePicker dp;int month;
    TimePicker tp;int year;long millisecond;
    Button ok;String data2;int hour;int datee;int minutes;
    BroadcastReceiver alarmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
        }
    };


    public static final String ACTION_NAME = "com.helloworld.MYACTION";
    private IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_NAME);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder);
        Intent in = getIntent();
         registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, myFilter);

        dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  year = dp.getYear();
                  datee = dp.getDayOfMonth();
                  month = dp.getMonth();
                  hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
                  minutes = tp.getCurrentMinute();// day//mm//yy//min//hr
            conversion_shit();
            }});        
}

    protected void conversion_shit() {
        int xhour;
        String xx;
        if(hour > 12)
        {
          xhour=     (hour)-12;
          xx="AM";

        }   
        else
        {  xx="PM";  xhour=(hour);
        }
        int monthint=(month);

        String date= String.valueOf(datee)+"/"+monthint+"/"+String.valueOf(year)+ " " +String.valueOf(xhour)+":"+String.valueOf(minutes)+":00 " + xx ;

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
        Date convertedDate = new Date();

            try {
                convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
                  millisecond = convertedDate.getTime();

            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(String.valueOf(millisecond),convertedDate.toString());

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(ACTION_NAME);
             PendingIntent   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Reminder.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millisecond, pendingIntent);

                        Toast.makeText(Reminder.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }








    }
```

Comment: not enough information to diagnose. all you say is that it appears to be `not working`, without any cluse as to why.

Comment: @njzk2 what extra info you want ?

Comment: Please, post the code of alarm manager and the `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: lets see, hum, the code that does not work, for one. any kind of log would nice, and, for instance, a description of your current debugging efforts? (I would not call that `extra`, though)

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy alarm manager is working fine without broadcast receiver,should i still post it's code?

Comment: you need to start defining words like `working fine`, `not working`... In other words, how do you know it does not work?

Comment: No, post now the declaration of the Receivers

Comment: @njzk2 omg seriously,will i not come to know if a thing is working or not ??just by printing some random thing in log or toast,any one can come to that conclusion.I hope you are not starting a grammar war over here

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy  posted the code

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava : Not a grammar war, no. My question is rather serious, on the contrary. See, I have no way of knowing how you tested you broadcastreceiver. Also, since apparently there is something that does not have the output you want, there is probably something that you are doing wrong. I usually start by covering the basics before considering a more complex issue.

Comment: For example, instead of `it does not work`, something in the lines of `This line is never reached in the debugger` or `This logs does not get printed` is quite clearer.

Comment: @njzk2 okay sorry my bad..... i created a toast,so that if it was working,it would have displayed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PendingIntent.getService` is for services, as the name suggests.

For `BroadcastReceiver`, use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`