# Background service for android (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin

I am currently using Xamarin to develop an android application.
What is the best way to add an background service to my application. It must always run if the app is open or closed. And  it must interact with the application database without opening it.

For example the application must check every 5 mins if it must send a notification this check is based on the data saved in the application itself

Comment: https://github.com/AshishGarg1988/XamarinSamples/tree/master/ForeGroundService Check this where you can create Service which runs continuously even after kill app work for android fine

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in your question: Youe need to implement an [Android service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). You will find tons of tutorials and info sites in the web (just search for it).

First entry: [Backgrounding with Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/)

If you have some specific questions, ask here again.

Answer (score 1):

For background service your best bet is Broadcast Receiver. Here you can read more about [broadcastreceiver](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/broadcast-receivers/) and for your second question of checking every 5 mins for updates can be done by using alarm manager along with broadcast receiver, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31838628/1921481) can guide you more